# Using a class function in another class

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, stack, header-files

I have a LinkedList.h header file which runs perfectly. I am trying to use that LinkedList to implement a stack. The issue is in using the functions from the LinkedList class in this MyStack class. InsertFront(key) is a function in the LinkedList class. Now when I run it, I get the following 2 errors.

**'list' : undeclared identifier**

**left of '.InsertFront' must have class/struct/union**

Both of these refer to the last line of the following code:

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



class MyStack
{
    private:
    //LinkedList list;


    public:
        //Implement the following functions whose purpose should be obvious
        MyStack();
        ~MyStack();
        void Push(int key);
        int Pop();
        bool isEmpty();
        int Size();
        void Display(); // Just show the elements from top of stack to the bottom without removing them
        int Top(); // Return the element at the top of the stack without removing it
};


MyStack::MyStack()
{
    LinkedList list;
}

MyStack::~MyStack()
{

}

void MyStack::Push(int key)
{

    list.InsertFront(key);
}
```

The cpp file is as follows:

```
#include "MyStack.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MyStack s;
    int value, choice;
    do{
        cout << "Enter 1 to push,\n2 to pop,\n3 to display the contents of the stack,\n4 to display the item at the top of the stack,\n5 to find the size of the queue,\n0 to quit"<<endl;
        cin >> choice;
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                cout << "Key: ";
                cin >> value;
                s.Push(value);
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "The item removed from the top of the stack is: " << s.Pop() << endl;
                break;
            case 3:
                s.Display();
                break;
            case 4: 
                cout << "The item at the top of the stack is: " << s.Top() << endl;
                break;
            case 5: 
                cout << "The size of the stack is: " << s.Size() << endl;;
            case 0:
                break;
        }
    } while (choice != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your linked list member is commented out.

Answer (score 6):

You commented out the declaration of your `LinkedList` and instead made it a local variable to the constructor. How is the rest of the class supposed to know about `LinkedList list` when it goes out of scope as soon as you finish the constructor?

Comment: I commented it out because when I uncomment it I get a lot of errors and when i click on them it says system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Some of the errors:
1>c:\users\vaio\documents\downloads\ds\assignment2\linkedlist.h(155): warning C4715: 'LinkedList::Read' : not all control paths return a value
1>c:\users\vaio\documents\downloads\ds\assignment2\linkedlist.h(182): warning C4715: 'LinkedList::Find' : not all control paths return a value
1>usestack.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall MyStack::Size(void)" (?Size@MyStack@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function _main

Comment: You need to uncomment it and fix those errors, then, because without that line, your code will not know what LinkedList you are looking for. Two of the errors you posted are in `LinkedList.h`, which you have not posted. The other one simply says that you never defined the `int Size()` function in your `MyStack` class.

Comment: What should i put in the constructor then?

Comment: Without knowing the specifics of your implementation, I'm not sure. It doesn't look like you need anything there at the moment, though.